# How do I create a drop down list that allows a user to choose a month?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

Right now I have this and it all works fine.

```
PossibleExpirationMonths = creditCardInterpreter.GetPossibleMonths()
```

The GetPossibleMonths method:

```
    public List<dynamic> GetPossibleMonths()
    {
        return new List<dynamic>()
        {
            new {Display = "01 Jan", Value = 1 },
            new {Display = "02 Feb", Value = 2 },
            new {Display = "03 Mar", Value = 3 },
            new {Display = "04 Apr", Value = 4 },
            new {Display = "05 May", Value = 5 },
            new {Display = "06 Jun", Value = 6 },
            new {Display = "07 Jul", Value = 7 },
            new {Display = "08 Aug", Value = 8 },
            new {Display = "09 Sep", Value = 9 },
            new {Display = "10 Oct", Value = 10 },
            new {Display = "11 Nov", Value = 11 },
            new {Display = "12 Dec", Value = 12 }
        };
    }
```

and how I'm displaying it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExpirationMonth, new SelectList(Model.PossibleExpirationMonths, "Value", "Display"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to test the method and access the Display and Value properties of the dynamic like

```
returnedList.First().Display
```

I get an error. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Display'

The reason I want to use dynamics here is because I don't feel like I should create a container class that contains such a little amount of information. It just creates bloat and I'm TRYING to be cleaner.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: How are you populating `returnedList`?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry you feel that way. Use `KeyValuePair<int, String>` instead if you really want to reduce lines of code at any cost. Did `List<object>` fail the same way?

Comment: ...at the end of the day, though, I've been doing this for a living for 20 years and I see nothing wrong with writing a quickie class for that purpose. This is nuclear over-thinking.

Comment: I'm not saying that writing a container class is wrong. I'm just doing something that would make the solution explorer have one file less, I'm not tied to this way of doing it.

Comment: Why are you using `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<SelectListItem>` which is what your ultimately need anyway? And it can be as simple as `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months() { return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeForm‌at.GetMonthName(x) }); }`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.First()` always returns type `Object`.   You can try:

```
((dynamic)returnedList.First()).Display
```

I think you might be re-inventing the wheel a bit, though. Why aren't you using a [`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar control?  All of the things you're wanting out of this are properties of a `DateTime` (specifically, `DateTime.Month`) .  For the web, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469280/asp-net-datetime-picker) works well.

Comment: Mmmm, First() was my way of trying to simplify it for the sake of the question. I still cannot access .Display off an object cast to a dynamic.